# Migrate Django model to Postgresql schema

Tags: django, postgresql, database-schema

I would like to create a new table in a specific Postgresql schema (i.e. "schema1) from a Django migration.

Despite following approach 1 from [this blog](https://www.amvtek.com/blog/posts/2014/Jun/13/accessing-multiple-postgres-schemas-from-django/) or [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51007441/3976696), the migration sends the table to the default schema "public" instead of "schema1".

In `settings.py`, I have:

```
DATABASES = {

    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'OPTIONS': {
                        'options': '-c search_path=django,public'
                    },
        'NAME': 'myDB',
        'USER': 'username',
        'PASSWORD': '***',
        'HOST': 'my.host.address',
        'PORT': '1234',
    },

    'schema1': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'OPTIONS': {
                    'options': '-c search_path=schema1,public'
                },
    'NAME': 'myDB',
    'USER': 'username',
    'PASSWORD': '***',
    'HOST': 'my.host.address',
    'PORT': '1234',
    } 
}  


#Path to DBrouter to handle PG schemas https://stackoverflow.com/a/51007441/3976696
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ('djangogirls.dbrouters.MyDBRouter',)
```

In `djangogirls/dbrouters.py`, I have:

```
from legacydbapp.models import MyUser

# Include here any class (i.e. table) that belongs to the schema "schema1"
ROUTED_MODELS_SCHEMA1 = [MyUser]


class MyDBRouter(object):
    """
    A router to place DB queries into correct schema depending on considered tables.
    """
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model in ROUTED_MODELS_SCHEMA1 :
            return 'schema1'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model in ROUTED_MODELS_SCHEMA1 :
            return 'schema1'
        return None
```

And the model class I'm trying to migrate, in `models.py`:

```
class MyUser(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='',null=True, blank=True) 
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='', null=True, blank=True)
    profession = models.CharField(max_length=32,default='', null=True, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'myuser'
```

I ran the following commands:

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations legacydbapp
$ python manage.py sqlmigrate legacydbapp 0001_initial
$ python manage.py migrate legacydbapp
```

And the sqlmigrate returns the following SQL:

```
BEGIN;
--
-- Create model MyUser
-- 
CREATE TABLE "myuser" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    "first_name" varchar(30) NULL, 
    "last_name" varchar(30) NULL, 
    "profession" varchar(32) NULL); 
COMMIT;
```

If the DB router were working, I would expect the SQL to read instead `CREATE TABLE "schema1.myuser"`, but this isn't the case. Did I mess up somewhere, or is this simply not achievable in Django 2.1.5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to explicitly provide the name of the database definition when running migrate:

```
$ python manage.py migrate legacydbapp --database schema1
```

To ensure that the model `MyUser` is only created in a specific database, your router has to implement [`.allow_migrate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/multi-db/#allow_migrate)

Comment: Thanks, this worked once I specified `--database schema1`. However, I didn't need to implement `allow_migrate()`. If I understand the docs correctly, this would be a safeguard to silently prevent migrations to apply in unauthorized schemas (e.g. in case one forgets to specify the DB with `--database schema1`). I would appreciate if you could confirm this, or indicate if there are any other risks not implementing any `allow_migrate()` function.

Comment: That's my understanding, too. If you always call `migrate` with an appname and the database parameter, you probably don't need to implement `allow_migrate`. However, if you call `migrate` without any parameters, it will apply migrations from all apps, including your `legacydbapp`.

Comment: This does not work for me. I get `django.db.utils.ConnectionDoesNotExist: The connection schema1 doesn't exist`

Comment: @Stefan_Fairphone you have to replace `schema1` with the appropriate connection name from your `DATABASES` setting

Comment: Yeah, I know, but the database is called `postgres` and has multiple schemas. I used `schema1` for the purpose of being in line with your answer.

Comment: @Stefan_Fairphone I guess it would be best to ask a separate question with your `DATABASES` setting

Comment: In my case I first had to manually `CREATE SCHEMA schema1`. Then migration worked.

Answer (score -2):

hi to migrate one model to specific scema you can use:

```
python manage.py migrate -s schema1
```

Comment: I don't see this anywhere in the Django docs. Where did you get the `-s` parameter from?

Comment: in django 4 "python manage.py migrate -s schema1"

Comment: I don't understand why this answer was marked as not useful. You just saved my day bro. I just wanted to create dummy schema for postgress fallback search. This command just worked as a charm.