# Django "relation does not exist" error with custom user class and Postgresql schemas

Tags: python, django, postgresql, database-schema

I am getting a `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "user" does not exist` error when running `createsuperuser` on a Django project with a Postgresql database.

I wrote the following database router to indicate that the table `user` (which is based on a custom extension of the `AbstractUser` class) is in the schema `users`. Even so, Django cannot find it.

```
from myapp.models import Class1, Class2, Class3
from users.models import User
from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session

# Include here classes (i.e. tables) that belongs to the "myapp" schema
ROUTED_MODELS_MYAPP = [Class1, Class2, Class3]

# Include here classes (i.e. tables) that belongs to the "users" schema
ROUTED_MODELS_USERS = [User, LogEntry, ContentType, Session] #classes for custom user model, and django tables `django_admin_log`, `django_content_type`, `django_session` tables
# classes for the following table names still missing from list: `auth_group`, `auth_group_permissions`, `auth_permission`.

class MyDBRouter(object):
    """
    A router to place DB queries into correct schema depending on considered tables.
    Sources: 
        https://stackoverflow.com/a/51007441/3976696
        https://www.amvtek.com/blog/posts/2014/Jun/13/accessing-multiple-postgres-schemas-from-django/
    """
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model in ROUTED_MODELS_MYAPP:
            return 'myapp'
        elif model in ROUTED_MODELS_USERS:
            return 'users'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model in ROUTED_MODELS_MYAPP:
            return 'myapp'
        elif model in ROUTED_MODELS_USERS:
            return 'users'        
        return None
```

The router works for other tables unrelated to authentication, so I suspect this has to do with the other tables automatically created by Django when I migrated the User class for the first time (`auth_group`, `auth_group_permissions`, `auth_permission`, `django_admin_log`, `django_content_type`, `django_session`).

However, I'm not sure:

1. If the router is supposed to be written like I did (a sequence of
   `if`/`elif`) -->  is there a better way to write a router for more than one schema?
2. Which are the model names corresponding to the
   Django tables listed above. --> I was able to guess the three last class names (`django_admin_log`, `django_content_type`, `django_session`) by looking into `django/contrib` directories, but how am I supposed to find those for `auth_group`, `auth_group_permissions`, `auth_permission`?

**EDIT:** based on the comment from @Kevin, I tried writing the routers based on `app_label`s rather than model names, as shown in the docs, making one router for each app involved. I also tried manually specifying the `app_label` in the Meta class of my User class (i.e. `app_label = 'users'`).

However the original error (`django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "user" does not exist`) persists when I enter a username in `createsuperuser`. How else am I supposed to handle this situation in the router?

```
#Route all models in admin application, cf. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/multi-db/
class AdminRouter:
    """
    A router to control all database operations on models in the admin application.
    """
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to read admin models go to users.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'admin':
            return 'users'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to write admin models go to users.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'admin':
            return 'users'
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        """
        Make sure the admin app only appears in the 'users' database.
        """
        if app_label == 'admin':
            return db == 'users'
        return None

class AuthRouter:
    """
    A router to control all database operations on models in the
    auth application.
    """
    <similar to previous router>

class ContentTypeRouter:
    """
    A router to control all database operations on models in the
    contenttype application.
    """
    <similar to previous router>

class SessionRouter:
    """
    A router to control all database operations on models in the
    sessionapplication.
    """
    <similar to previous router>

#Route all models in users application, cf. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/multi-db/
class UsersRouter:
    """
    A router to control all database operations on models in the users application.
    """
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to read user models go to users.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'users':
            return 'users'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to write user models go to users.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'users':
            return 'users'
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        """
        Make sure the user app only appears in the 'users' database.
        """
        if app_label == 'users':
            return db == 'users'
        return None
```

Then, I call them from `settings.py` in the following order:

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = (
                    'urbio.dbrouters.AdminRouter',
                    'urbio.dbrouters.AuthRouter', 
                    'urbio.dbrouters.ContentTypeRouter', 
                    'urbio.dbrouters.SessionRouter', 
                    'urbio.dbrouters.UsersRouter',
                    )
```

Comment: Instead of listing the models, it would seem easier to use the method shown in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#an-example): `if model._meta.app_label == 'auth':`.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry thanks for the suggestion. I tried that (see edit in original post), but unfortunately it didn't seem to work ether. Would you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to specify the `--database` flag and point to the correct schema when running the `createsuperuser` command:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser --database users
```

Also, following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51007441/3976696), the database definition in `settings.py` is:

```
DATABASES = {

    'default': 
            {},

    'schema1': 
            {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'OPTIONS': {
                            'options': '-c search_path=schema1'
                        },
            'NAME': 'mydbname',
            'USER': 'myusername',
            'PASSWORD': '***',
            'HOST': 'my.host.address',
            'PORT': '5432',
            },

    'users': 
            {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'OPTIONS': {
                            'options': '-c search_path=users'
                        },
            'NAME': 'mydbname',
            'USER': 'myusername',
            'PASSWORD': '***',
            'HOST': 'my.host.address',
            'PORT': '5432',
            }

}
```

Comment: The correct syntax in the latest version is `--database=db_name`