# How to create tables in a different schema in django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm

I'm using postgresql database in my django project.

I have multiple apps in my projects.

```
users/
    UserProfile model
myapp/
    CustomModel model
```

Now I need `UserProfile` table should be created in `public` schema
And `CustomModel` table needs to be created in a separate schema called `myapp`

How to implement this and Do I need to change anything in the queries or migration command in future after implementing this?

Comment: Yes, this adds quite a bit of complexity, you may wish to [refer to this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50819748/django-and-postgresql-schemas).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use a meta information:

```
class User(models.Model)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'schema"."tablename'
```

I've been using it from some time and found not problem so far.

More info:
This will replace table name in all your database queries with `db_table`. So any query will `SELECT * FROM "tablename"` will be converted to `SELECT * FROM "geo"."tablename"`. Its just a neat trick, hopefully Django gives this option natively in future.

Comment: So, I just need to `'myapp"."custom_model'` as `db_table` in my `CustomModel` class and `user_profile` as `db_table` in my `UserProfile` model? will that do everything I mentioned for me? And will that create the schema `myapp` automatically? can you add more details to your solution? It will be more helpful.

Comment: No it won't create the schema for you. That you need to do manually.
And yes for `CustomModel` you need to do that. And since you are creating `UserProfile` in public, you can just remove the `db_table` attribute and let Django do its thing.

Comment: As you mentioned `SELECT * FROM "geo"."tablename"` will select the table from the schema `geo`, will that also create the table in the `geo` schema while running `migrate` command?

Answer (score 0):

FOr Sql Server Use

```
class User(models.Model)
class Meta:
    db_table = '[schema].[tablename]'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).