# Django how to create model tables in a specific schema

Tags: django, database, django-models

So this is the question:
Let's say I have 2 schemas in my database:
**schema1** and **schema2**

I have a simple user table and a simple car table

```
class User(models.Model)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user'


class Car(models.Model)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'car'
```

I want the **user** table to be in **schema1**

And the **car** table is to be in **schema2**

How would you guys go about doing this?

I saw a post that said I need to specify int he db_table = 'schema_name"."table_name'
But that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in link below, you need to specify schema name and table name in db_table, so your Meta class for User should look like this (with default schema):

```
class Meta: 
    db_table = 'public"."user'
```

And for Car (assuming schema called "new"):

```
class Meta: 
    db_table = 'new"."car'
```

Don't forget to migrate this.

[How to create tables in a different schema in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72751166/how-to-create-tables-in-a-different-schema-in-django)

Comment: This is so weird. I saw that post and even specified in my question that this way doesn't work for me for some reason. But I rerun the code on a different PC and it worked. maybe the django version or something I did with the migrations. either way it worked so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your suggesting something like this:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    age = models.PositiveBigIntegerField()
    class Meta: 
        db_table = 'user'

class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    model = models.PositiveBigIntegerField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    class Meta: 
        db_table = 'car'
```

Here we are using a `owner` in `Car` model to create a relationship to `User` model.

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer, but nowhere in my question I was talking about relationships between tables. The question was how can I create each table in a different schema.