# How to create tables in different schemas using Geodjango and Postgres/ PostGIS?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, postgis, geodjango

My question is very similar to the question asked and answered here, using the Meta class and db_table = 'schema"."tablename' approach to use multiple schemas:
[How to create tables in a different schema in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72751166/how-to-create-tables-in-a-different-schema-in-django)

This solution worked for me under the standard Django project framework (using **django.db models**); however, once I attempted to use this method in a Geodjango project (using **django.contrib.gis.db models**), I received the following error when trying to migrate a model that included geospatial fields (PointField, LineStringField, and PolygonField):

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "."
LINE 1: CREATE INDEX "schema"."tablename_geom_point_id" ON "sch...
```

How can I implement this approach using Geodjango to leverage the benefits of schemas directly in the model?

Example code of what I tried and resulted in the error message has been presented below.

*models.py*

```
import uuid
from django.contrib.gis.db import models


class TableName(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key = True, default = uuid.uuid4, editable = False)
    ...
    geom_point = models.PointField(blank=True, null=True)
    geom_line = models.LineStringField(blank=True, null=True)
    geom_polygon = models.PolygonField(blank=True, null=True)    
    ...
    
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'schema"."tablename'
```

Thank you for any support you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with the way schema and table names are specified when using geodjango, while working with geospatial fields, the naming conventions and behavior can/may be different from regular Django models.

You can perhaps enclose them in `''` rather than the `""` just for the `.` - which is the conventional way for sql tables. This is most likely the issue.

```py
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class TableName(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    # ...
    geom_point = models.PointField(blank=True, null=True)
    geom_line = models.LineStringField(blank=True, null=True)
    geom_polygon = models.PolygonField(blank=True, null=True)
    # ...

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'schema.tablename'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Although this approach does allow the model to be successfully migrated to the database, it doesn't result in the desired behaviour. Instead of the table(s) being created in the specified schema, it is added to the default/ public schema with a name of "schema.tablename.geom_point".

Please advise if you have any additional suggestions. Thanks!